# 'Media-queries' for javascript - different code for different viewport height/widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, viewport

**The problem**

I'm using javascript to calculate widths of elements to achieve the layout I'm after. The problem is, I don't want to load the code on smaller screen sizes *(when the screen width is less than 480px for example)*. I'd like this to work on load and on browser/viewport resize.

I'd consider small screen devices 'the default' and working up from there. So, none of the following script is called by default, then if the browser width is greater than 480px (for example), the following script would be called:

**The code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Get the figures width
    var figure_width = $(".project-index figure").css("width").replace("px", "");

    //Get num figures
    var num_figures = $(".project-index figure").length;

    //Work out how manay figures per row
    var num_row_figures = Math.ceil(num_figures / 2);

    //Get the total width
    var row_width = figure_width * num_row_figures;

    //Set container width to half the total
    $(".project-index").width(row_width);

    x = null;
    y = null;

    $(".project-index div").mousedown(function(e) {
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
    });

    $(".project-index div").mouseup(function(e) {
        if (x == e.clientX && y == e.clientY) {
            //alert($(this).next().attr("href"));
            window.location.assign($(this).next().attr("href"));
        }
        x = y = null;
    });

});

// Drag-on content
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#main').dragOn();
});
```

**The extra bit**

The slight difference on larger screens is to do with the browser/viewport height. This is in regards to the line:

`var num_row_figures = Math.ceil(num_figures / 2);`

You can see once the calculation has a value, it divides it by 2. I only want this to happen when the browser/viewport height is above a certain amount - say 600px.

I'd be happy with this being the 1st state and then the value is divided by 2 if the height is greater than 600px if it's easier.

Can anyone help me/shed some light on how to manage my script this way. I know there's media queries for managing CSS but I can't seem to find any resources for how to manage javascript this way - hope someone can help.

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia), which is the javascript equivalent of media queries. The matchMedia call creates a [mediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) object. We can query the mediaQueryList object matches property to get the state, and attach an event handler using `mediaQueryList.addListener` to track changes.

I've added an example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duep7L1k/2/) of using matchMedia on load and on resize. Change the bottom left pane height and width (using the borders), and see the states of the two queries.

This is the code I've used:

```
<div>Min width 400: <span id="minWidth400"></span></div>
<div>Min height 600: <span id="minHeight600"></span></div>

var matchMinWidth400 = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)"); // create a MediaQueryList
var matchMinHeight600 = window.matchMedia("(min-height: 600px)"); // create a MediaQueryList

var minWidth400Status = document.getElementById('minWidth400');
var minHeight600Status = document.getElementById('minHeight600');

function updateMinWidth400(state) {
    minWidth400Status.innerText = state;
}

function updateMinHeight600(state) {
    minHeight600Status.innerText = state;
}

updateMinWidth400(matchMinWidth400.matches); // check match on load

updateMinHeight600(matchMinHeight600.matches); // check match on load

matchMinWidth400.addListener(function(MediaQueryListEvent) { // check match on resize
    updateMinWidth400(MediaQueryListEvent.matches);
});

matchMinHeight600.addListener(function(MediaQueryListEvent) { // check match on resize
    updateMinHeight600(MediaQueryListEvent.matches);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will this work on resize as well as load? I couldn't get it to work but I'm not that experienced a javascript coder! Do you have an example with the matchMedia/QueryList involving code?

Comment: I've add a more detailed example and a fiddle - note that it doesn't work for IE9 and below, although you can patch that with a polyfill - https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
}
```

So i searched a bit and came up with this example from w3 schools .http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1
i think this is something you are trying to achieve.

For pure js , you can get the screen width by screen.width

Comment: Thanks, that's just for CSS though, unfortunately it doesn't work for javascript :(

Comment: so why not get the screen.width property in js ?