# Window.Resize stop propogation to higher breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have dynamically created elements that react differently at different window sizes. These sizes are dynamic and can be passed in by an array from the user. For example, an object array like `{500 : 3, 300: 1}` will display 3 items at 500px and 1 item at 300px. I create these listeners on init:

```
    var sizesArray = {500 : 3, 300: 1};
    var numItems = shownItems;
    $.each(sizesArray, function(key, value) {
            $(window).on("resize", elem, function () {
                 if ($(window).width() <= key) {                         
                       shownItems = value;          
                 } else {
                       shownItems = numItems;           
                 }
            });
     })
```

So, essentially this is saying for each pair in the list create an resize listener. When the window is below the given size change the number of items shown to the value. When it's not below that size return to the default size.

This works fine when there is only one key/value in the array, but when there is two it gets messy. With the array `{500 : 3, 300: 1}` when the window is below 500 it goes to 3 items like expected but when the window is below 300px both events are firing and it is still staying at 3 items not the expected 1.

I've tried adding `stopPropogation()`, `stopImmediatePropogation()`, and `preventDefault()` but none seem to work. Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Use window.matchMedia instead of resize event handler - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969829/media-queries-for-javascript-different-code-for-different-viewport-height-wi/31970094#31970094

Comment: @OriDrori that is helpful and I may use that instead of my conditionals but it seems to still have the same problem of propagating to both sizes

Comment: Just the specific listener that matches the change is fired each time, so if you have 300, 500, 700 width, when you enlarge the screen each of them will be fired once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one `resize` event, and then iterate the object. When you iterate the object, just break the loop whenever you get a `true` value, and that will prevent the other checks:

```
var sizesArray = [{ size: 300, value: 1 }, { size: 500, value: 3}]; // use an array that contains size objects listed from the smallest size to the largest to avoid browsers differences when iterating objects
var numItems = shownItems;

$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    shownItems = numItems; // reset the number of shown items

    $.each(sizesArray, function (index, sizeObj) { // iterate sizes array
        if (width <= sizeObj.size) { // if width <= key return false - break the loop, so the other checks won't occur
            shownItems = sizeObj.value;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The example uses window.matchMedia. Inspect the console of the right bottom pane of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0nsa40ah/3/) to see the changes:

```
var sizesArray = [{ // should be sorted from smallest to largest
    size: 300,
    value: 1
}, {
    size: 500,
    value: 3
}];

var lastQueryIndex = sizesArray.length - 1; // cache the index of the last query

var numItems = shownItems;

sizesArray.forEach(function (query, index) {
    var match = window.matchMedia("(max-width: " + query.size + "px)"); // create the queries

    match.addListener(function (mediaQueryListEvent) { // check match on resize
        console.log(query.size, match.matches);
        mediaQueryListEvent.matches && updateState(query.value);
        index === lastQueryIndex && !mediaQueryListEvent.matches && updateState(numItems); // for the last query, check if bigger to restore default
    });

    console.log(query.size, match.matches);
    match.matches && updateState(query.value); // update onload
});

function updateState(value) {
    shownItems = value;
    console.log(shownItems);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very expensive function, wouldn't iterating over an array every resize (which fires every pixel), for potentially multiple objects be really inefficient? Also I don't think I can use matchMedia as it has no way to set the size back to default when the screen gets bigger

Comment: I'm not sure what denounce and throttle are but I assume it's some sort of plugin? I'm actually using this code in my own plugin so I'm not trying to include others. And for match media the user can set any numbers in the array so without running more checks to see what's the largest number that won't work (although that may be the solution). Either way you're correct these arrays won't be large so I'll try this idea and see how t works.

Comment: Deleted and restored because the spell checker changed debounce to denounce: 
The usual remedy is using debounce or throttle to minimise the amount of handler execution. Anyway, it's a small array, and I'm not sure if setting a large amount of resize handlers is more performant. In matchMedia use "bigger then the last size in the array" as the default.

Comment: [Debounce and throttle](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls) are simple functions: Debounce postpones execution until x time has passed since the last time we invoked the function. Throttle allows only one execution every x time. You can create matchMedia queries in a loop, and then identify the last. I'll add an example.